# The method getIntentSender() is undefined for the type ConnectionResult

Tags: android, google-plus

I tried to use a [Google+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%2B) login in my app.

While writing code, I am getting this problem:

> The method getIntentSender() is undefined for the type
>   ConnectionResult

I added permissions for Internet, getaccounts, and usecredentials. I added the Google+ services library.

The code is here:

```
package com.niranjan.googleplus;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleapi;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        googleapi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API, null)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .build();

    }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        googleapi.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(googleapi.isConnected()){
            googleapi.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(result.getIntentSender(),
                                           RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent. Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                googleapi.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!googleapi.isConnecting()) {
                googleapi.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        googleapi.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I have updated the code, but at run time I am getting a Nullpointer Exception...

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
result.getResolution().getIntentSender()
```

I had this problem and solved it that way.

Comment: Thank you I got it --@Itzik Samara

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null options are not permitted for this Api

 at com.google.android.gms.internal.hn.b(Unknown Source)

 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.addApi(Unknown Source)

 at com.niranjan.googleplus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)

Comment: please open new question cause i cant see the full Log or post it in your main question

Comment: Thank you @Itzik Samara problem raised because i did not use .addApi(Plus.API, null) properly i don't know why null pointer exception occured and i got the solution that is to change the command which i have given in other answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution on Stack Overflow.

I can get the application working using the below commands instead of `.addApi(Plus.API, null)`.

1. `addApi(Plus.API)`
2. `addApi(Plus.API, PlusOptions.builder().build())`

But what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

> **result.getStatus().hasResolution()**

**or**

> **if ( ( result.getStatus().getIntentSender() ) != null )
>   {
>         .........
>         .........
>   }**

Hope it helps.